# How to remove JS added in page.xml , in One Page Checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, onepage-checkout

In `page.xml`, I added `jQuery` in `page.xml` :

```
<action method="addJs">
  <script>lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js</script>
</action>
<action method="addJs">
  <script>lib/jquery/noconflict.js</script>
</action>
```

However, I have to remove jQuery in One Page Checkout page, which is controlled by `checkout.xml`. How can I remove the `jQuery` in One Page Checkout pages?

I'm using Magento 1.9.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try with this with `local.xml`

```
<checkout_onepage_index>       
    <reference name="head">            
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js</name> 
        </action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

if you wish to remove from `js` folder not `skin`

```
<checkout_onepage_index>       
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem">
            <type>js</type>
            <name>lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js</name>
        </action>    
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
```

Comment: Already tried this. Even if I cleared all the caches, the jQuery lines are still there. Note that the jQuery is at `{Magento_Dir}/js/lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.3.min.js`, not in skin folder.

Comment: i dont want to i have already added mine see my descriptive answer not like you to paste from other answer

Comment: no need to add <checkout_onepage_index translate="label">
translate label again in local.xml , you are just copied from net and added to your answer, i can't just stop on you to laugh

Comment: Thanks man, it works like charm ! (p.s. edit history of his answer will tell... lol)

Comment: @Raptor, Thanks a lot i will but another person who just know to search on web and answer will not edit it.:D like ahmed

Comment: I even called every one in the office to see this - we can't stop laughing  --- mr good reputation I copied the line form the base template not from some one else answer like you did ..  you maybe have good reputation because you free and have nothing to do in life.

Comment: i have lots to do and doing since long time, not like you to feel jealous on others answer,here i also show your answer before to all my collegues  and your are wrong thats way you deleted your asnwer. you can see mine is accepted and correct answer, :D

Comment: good luck mate, I promises you we will meet again

Comment: Best of luck to you and lots of wishes from my end, Sure we will :D